# Integrating routed Angular 2 App in exisiting App

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to integrate an Angular 2 (RC 2) App into a desktop application built with Electron and Angular 2 (RC 2). Existing App should not be changed significantly, so I am searching for a solution of simple integration.

I am using router "3.0.0-alpha.7" which should be the newest working with RC 2 (App cannot be updated at the moment because of dependencies).

Basically the existing App has a "Stage" where my Angular 2 App should simply be displayed. This is done by clicking on a button, which can toggle the content shown in the stage like this by changing a boolean:

**stage.html**

```
<div *ngIf="interfaceService.showInterface == false">
    <div class="stage-component component" *ngIf="fileHref">
        <div class="stage-wrapper">
            <webview [...]></webview>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="interfaceService.showInterface == true">
    <div class="stage-component component">
        <div class="stage-wrapper">
            <EntryComponent></EntryComponent>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Toggling works great so for, however I´ve got some trouble getting my routed App working withing the divs.
My EntryComponent only imports my App component and references it in template.

**entry.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {App} from '../../myapp.components/app.component/app.component';        

@Component({
    selector: 'EntryComponent',
    template: `
               <myapp></myapp>
              `,
    directives: [App]
})

export class EntryComponent {        
    constructor() {}    
}
```

App component contains my (child) router-outlet from which user should be redirected.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, provideRouter} from '@angular/router';
import {myAppRoutes} from '../myapp.routes';

@Component({
  selector: 'myapp',
  template: `            
            <router-outlet name="myappinterface"></router-outlet>
            `,
  directives : [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
  providers: [ provideRouter(myAppRoutes) ]
})

export class App {
  constructor(public router: Router) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
  }
}
```

MyApp-Routes look like following:

**myapp.routes**

```
import {RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';

import {Home} from './home.component/home.component';
import {Login} from './login.component/login.component';
import {Signup} from './signup.component/signup.component';
[...]
import {AuthGuard} from "./../../common/auth.guard";

export const databaseInterfaceRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home' },
    { path: 'home', component: Home, canActivate: [AuthGuard], outlet: 'myappinterface' },
    { path: 'login', component: Login, outlet: 'myappinterface' },
    { path: 'signup', component: Signup, outlet: 'myappinterface' },
    [...]
];
```

When trying to navigate to my app by clicking the button mentioned above error console tells me the following:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'home'

When removing

```
outlet: 'myappinterface'
```

from myapp.routes I do not get the error and I see component templates from my home-component being loaded in network monitor - but nothing is getting displayed.

Am I missing something important to get my routing working or is there an easier approach for integrating one Angular 2 App into another?
Thanks!

P.S.: If I missed something important to reproduce just tell me.

Comment: try removing outlet part from `{ path: 'home', component: Home, canActivate: [AuthGuard], outlet: 'myappinterface' },` as it was not part of the router that you are using currently. See if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Removing outlet gives me result described above: error gets away, I see templates being loaded correctly in network monitor but nothing is displayed. Problem might be this is my secondary outlet as my main App (where stuff is bootstrapped) has also an outlet:
`export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'main' },
    { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },
    { path: 'myapp/..', component: App },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'main'}
];`
That´s why I was trying to name my outlets.

Comment: Interface for route-config I am using also defines "outlet":
**config.d.ts**
`export interface Route {
    path?: string;
    terminal?: boolean;
    component?: Type | string;
    outlet?: string;
    canActivate?: any[];
    canDeactivate?: any[];
    redirectTo?: string;
    children?: Route[];
}`